# Is there a way to circumvent CA1726:UsePreferredTerms?

Tags: .net, code-analysis, suppression

I have a problem with the code analysis rule [CA1726:UsePreferredTerms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182258(VS.100).aspx). Our business domain has two crucial concepts named `Case` and `Flag`. According to CA, it's apparently a deadly sin to use these names, however I really don't care since, as I said, they are crucial concepts in our domain model. CA complains not only about the type declarations but about every method parameter-name aswell. So does anyone know if there is a workaround other than adding loads of suppressions or disabling the rule altogether? Could I add the names to a custom dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest adding the names to a custom dictionary as your first ditch effort, yes.  It's a dead-simple thing to do, and I've had to add a custom dictionary for every single non-trivial project that I've worked on for various problem-domain terms.

Comment: but CA1726 doesn't use preferred alternatives in CustomDictionary.xml. So Login will still raise warnings for instance.